# Socket.error: [Errno 10060] when connecting to MQTT broker

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to connect to my MQTT broker that is located on a Raspberry Pi. I am trying to publish to the RPi remotely using Wifi on my laptop. I have already verified that I can connect to the Raspberry Pi by connecting to it through SSH - port 22. However, when I try to run my code I get this error and apparently I fail to connect to the broker. Is there a way to fix this?

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/multi_mqtt.py", line 55, in <module>
    client.connect('10.xxx.xxx.xxx', 1883, 60)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 612, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py", line 734, in reconnect
    sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A timeout message at the socket level suggests that your firewall is blocking port 1883.

Comment: Oh now I remember that my university has blocked this port when using the wifi in my university. Thank you sir. Any suggestions to go around this? Change the port for example maybe?

Comment: Yes, you need to use a port that isn't blocked.

Comment: I mean, will it work with MQTT if I choose any random working port? Like port 100 for example?

Comment: As long as you configure the broker to use that port, you have nothing else listening on that port, yes.